# How to pass comboBox Values from One Window to Another Window by pressing puchButton in QT

Tags: qt

I am working on a project in which I want to pass `QComboBox` values from one window to another window. I don't know to do this.

Please guide me.

Comment: What have you tried ? Take a look to the Qt [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) page.

Comment: Not a real coding question. You are looking for a tutorial.

Comment: Sir ... I just need a pratical way.  Could you please show me an example , How I can pass these comboBox values Store them into integer variables. :|